# How to use username for Login using Sentinel in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, sentinel

I've using Sentinel for user authentication in Laravel.

I've followed [this](http://naomiaro.com/2015/07/08/multiple-login-attributes-with-sentinel-and-laravel/) guide to login using username but it doesn't seem to work!

I have a test route to test the login which is as follows:

```
Route::get('/test-login', function()
{
    Sentinel::authenticate([
        'login'    => 'nvaughan84',
        'password' => 'password',
    ]);

    //check login details
    if($user = Sentinel::check())
    {
        print_r($user);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Not Logged';
    }
});
```

I've created a Users model which extends SentinelUser as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser as SentinelUser;

class Users extends SentinelUser
{
    protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'username',
    'password',
    'last_name',
    'first_name',
    'permissions',
];

protected $loginNames = ['username'];
```

}

And I've updated my sentinel config:

```
'users' => [

    'model' => 'App\Users',

],
```

If I add 'username' to the $loginNames array in the Sentinel Class it works but not using my Users class which extends the Sentinel class.

Can someone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: I solved the problem but it now doesn't seem to keep the user logged in! It authenticates just fine but when I go to a different page Sentinel::check() return false despite the fact the use has logged in!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I stupidly still had

```
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Native\Facades\Sentinel;
```

at the top of my routes.php file and so it was using this instead of my new Users class!